# Bethe ansatz and density of states for XXX spin chain

Tags: quantum-spin, density-of-states, spin-chains

Consider the 1 dimensional Heisenberg antiferromagnet with Hamiltonian
$$ H = J\sum_{i=1}^L \vec S_i \cdot\vec S_{i+1}$$
and periodic boundary conditions.
I understand that this can be solved exactly by the Bethe ansatz which in principle gives one all the energies and eigenstates of the Hamiltonian in terms of linear combinations of states $|n_1,\dots,n_p\rangle$. These are states in the $\sigma_z$ basis where the spins at sites $n_1,\dots,n_p$ are in the $|\uparrow\rangle$ state and all others are in the $|\downarrow\rangle$ state.

For a chain of length $L$, any choice of $p$ from $1$ to $L$ will give $\binom L p$ eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian, which, summed over all $p$, gives the correct $2^N$ eigenvectors and eigenvalues in total. For each $p$, we need to solve the Bethe equations
$$ z_i^L = (-1)^{p-1} \prod_{j=1}^p \frac{z_iz_j-2z_i+1}{z_iz_j-2z_j+1}.$$
The corresponding energy, for a solution of the $z_j$, is $$E = L-4p + 2\sum_j z_j + 2\sum_k \frac{1}{z_j}$$
My questions are (1) how does one see that the Bethe equations indeed give us $\binom N p$ solutions for the $z_j$? and (2) how does one go about solving these at all? I am quite lost here. In particular I would appreciate any insight on what the distribution of eigenvalues is for this model, and whether this distribution can be calculated analytically from the Bethe ansatz. Or, can we calculate how the density of states vanishes at its edge? Any explanations or relevant references appreciated.